# Pass unfiltered requests for a specific endpoint

Tags: nginx, filter

I have an Nginx setup whereby I included a file with whitelisted IPs that can access my site's admin portal `admin.site.com`. Usually all users are redirected to to `site.com` if the response is 403 or 404 i.e. if their IP is not in the whitelist. Here is what I have

```
server {
    # listen on port 80 (http)
    listen 80;
    server_name admin.site.com;

    location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
        allow all;
        root /var/www/.well-known/acme-challenge/;
        default_type "text/plain";
        try_files $uri =404;
    }

    location / {
        # redirect any requests to the same URL but on https
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    # listen on port 443 (https)
    listen 443 http2 ssl;
    server_name admin.site.com;

    root /var/www/admin.site.com/site-frontend/;
    index index.html;
        location / {
       include /etc/nginx/snippets/whitelist.conf;
       error_page 403 404 =301 site.com;
    }

    # location of SSL certificate
    ssl_certificate /etc/some/path/admin.site.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/some/path/admin.site.com/privkey.pem;
    ...
    ...
    ...
```

How do I allow unfiltered traffic to certain endpoints e.g. `site.com/api/no-filters` for all traffic?

Comment: Use a `location` with `allow all;`. But it really depends on how Nginx will process the request, e.g. PHP or proxy_pass?

Comment: We use proxy_pass... can you share a sample config? Kindly...